# Elegant way to restrict PolynomialMod to non-negatives

Tags: polynomials, polynomialmod

Update at the bottom!

`PolynomialMod[4 + 10x, 1 + 2x]` returns `-1`. Instead, I'd like to get `4`, remainder `2x`, e. g. in a list, `{4, 2x}`. It would be quite inelegant if I had to "manually" get that as the minimum of 4/1 and 10/2.

I experimented with the brethren, `PolynomialGCD`, `PolynomialRemainder`, `PolynomialQuotient`, etc., but I couldn't find anything.

It is not important that I use `PolynomialMod`, that was just my starting point. What I am after has a bit of a flavor of a step in the Euclidean Algorithm. That too, is why I started with `PolynomialMod`, because the EA uses `Mod`.

I am looking primarily for code-efficient solutions: I can do discombobulating contortions on my own.

Update / Edit one day later based on responses:

So far I have (unfortunately a contortion)

```
func[num_,denom_]:=
With[{
a=MonomialList[num][[1,1]],
b=MonomialList[num][[2]],
c=MonomialList[denom][[1,1]],
d=MonomialList[denom][[2]]
},
With[{min=Floor@Min[a/c,b/d]},
{min,(a-min c)x+b-min d}]];
```

On examples

```
func[10x+4,2x+1]
func[70x+29,12x+5]
func[12x+37,78x+11]
func[68x+81,12x+6]
func[68x+6,12x+81]
func[68x+81,12x+55]
```

it does what I want, but my function `func` seems an ugly hack. No, not because of the multiply-nested `With`. I won't go into my preference for immutables, *that* is not the problem. The problem is the "manual mechanics" on a coefficient level, it would be better if I could do that with a top-level M function.

Comment: The `Mod` function in Mathematica takes a third argument that allows you to "shift the origin", so to speak, but it doesn't seem as if `PolynomialMod` has something similar.

Comment: Can you simply exactly describe what the result should be for any `a+b*x` and `c+d*x` giving `e+f*x`? Will `a,b,c,d` always be positive integers? Will `e==a/c` and `f==b-e*d`? I'm guessing not, but without a precise spec I don't see how to code up a function that gives you what you want. If you could find an algorithm for `PolynomialMod` then maybe you could adjust that to give what you want. The MMA docs say `PolynomialMod` is done with subtraction and no division, so maybe that is a hint.

Comment: Homogenize both polynomials using a new variable, PolynomialMod with respect to that variable, then (in general) set it to one ( that is, dehomogenize). See [WFR for homogenizing](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolynomialHomogenize/?i=PolynomialHomogenize&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch).

Comment: Alternatively replace x->1/x and maybe clear denominators. Replace back when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions are equivalent and work with any degree polynomials in `x`.

```
fu1[p_, q_ /; Not[q === 0]] := {Length[#] - 2, #[[-2]]} &@
  NestWhileList[# - q &, p, 
   CoefficientList[#, x] \[Element] NonNegativeIntegers &]

fu2[p_, q_ /; Not[q === 0]] := {n, Expand[p - n q]} /. 
  n -> MaxValue[{n, CoefficientList[p - n q, x] >= 0}, n, 
    NonNegativeIntegers]
```

Example 1:

```
fu1[10 x + 4, 2 x + 1]
fu2[10 x + 4, 2 x + 1]
```

---

```
{4, 2 x}

{4, 2 x}
```

Example 2:

```
fu1[10 x^3 + 41 x^2 + 15 x + 26, 2 x^3 + 3 x + 5]
fu2[10 x^3 + 41 x^2 + 15 x + 26, 2 x^3 + 3 x + 5]
```

---

```
{5, 1 + 41 x^2}

{5, 1 + 41 x^2}
```

Comment: Clever. With fu1 you subtract q until the coefficient list starts to have negative elements, and with fu2 you increase n as long as the coefficient list is still non-negative. I had never see MaxValue used that way. Really cool.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without contortions according to the docs:

> When m is a polynomial, PolynomialMod[poly,m] reduces poly by subtracting polynomial multiples of m, to give a result with minimal degree and leading coefficient.

I forget what this is called where you make the constant term the leading term and the leading term the constant term. But I think it has a name. Anyway, do it, then reduce the one mod the other, and then switch the monomial back.

```
{4 + 10 x, 1 + 2 x} // 
   u^1 # /. x -> 1/u & // (* u^1 because both polys are degree 1 *)
  Apply@PolynomialMod //
 #/u /. u -> 1/x &

(* 2 x *)
```

Comment: One might be able to use lattice reduction, e.g., `LatticeReduce[CoefficientList[{4 + 10 x, 1 + 2 x}, x]]`, but I'm not sure what `LatticeReduce` guarantees for its output. It's clear it can be used in this single instance, but I'm not sure about it in general.

Comment: It’s called variously the reciprocal or reflected or reversed polynomial.